# Where can I find submitted Linux patches?

Tags: linux-kernel

Is there a central repository that holds Linux kernel/driver patches that have been submitted, but not yet integrated into a kernel release? Ideally, such a repository would be searchable by kernel version(s) to which the patches apply, as well as subject (i.e. place in the kernel source tree), and by architecture (e.g. ARM), as well as manufacturer's processor family and board
(e.g OMAP3, BeagleBoard).

Answer (score 1):

Kernel.org has the kernel and patches that directly apply to the kernel.  The developers of specific subsystems have there own website where the develop drivers/patches/ and etc before they are submitted to the kernel.  The TV cards subsystem has linuxtv.org and the sound system has http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page.

I don't know, do you want a kernel patch or a driver patch?

[image: kernel.org]

Answer (score 0):

Each subsystem maintainer has his [own git tree](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/), where patches are included, tested before been merged in linus (official) tree.

For ARM arch, it is certainly the [arm-soc](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/arm/arm-soc.git/) one.